# DialogFragment disappears after calling startActivityForResult

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult

I call `startActivity` from a `DialogFragment`. However, when I get the result from calling `getActivity().startactivityforResult()`, my dialog is no longer visible.
I can't seem to call `startActivityForResult()` since `onActivityResult` doesn't seem to get called unless calling from my activity.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance()){
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

I've tried overriding onDestroyView.
However, on my activity's onActiivtyResult, my dialog isn't null, but also isResumed() and isVisible() will return false. I want to be able to pass the data returned from startActivityForResult to my dialogfragment. How can i do this?

```
@Override
onActivityResult(....)
    if(uploadFileSourceFragment != null){
         uploadFileSourceFragment.onActivityResult(...)
}
```

Comment: can you post the code where you start the new activity?

Answer (score 1):

Call `startActivityOnResult()` from your fragment instead of calling it from your activity.

Comment: I've tried calling startActivityForResult from my fragment, however that causes onActivityResult to not be called in my dialogfragment.

I also get this error in my logcat "activity result no fragment exists for index"